# SKSpriteNode uses up memory when physicsBody is created

Tags: swift, xcode, memory, sprite-kit, collision

I have a SKSpriteNode that uses no memory when sitting there.  Once I specify the physicsBody, the memory goes up at about 0.5MB per second.  I have other physics bodies but when they are added, they work normally.  There is a sprite called "player" which i use to display the player.  I made this function to make sure the problem was isolated. (IOS 10.3.3)

```
func createPlayerCollisionBox() {
    let playerDummy = SKSpriteNode()
    playerDummy.position = player.position
    playerDummy.name = "dummy"
    playerDummy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(circleOfRadius: 40)
    playerDummy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    playerDummy.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = false
    playerDummy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = playerCategory
    playerDummy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = UInt32(8)
    playerDummy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory | enemyCategory
    self.addChild(playerDummy)
}
```

Note: The memory does not go back down when you leave the scene and come back. 
The memory:
[image: Memory increasing]

Comment: Seems like there is  a strong reference cycle  somewhere in your application ... So, what you going to do is: 1) override deinits of scenes and all of your custom classes and check if deinit is called in every case. 2) search for usage of strong `self` within closures (especially if a closure is a part of a sequence that repeats forever) and replace them appropriately with unwoned or weak self. Also this code doesn't tell much. You just create a node, make its physics body, and add the node to the scene. Pretty much usual stuff. It is important later what you do with a player...

Comment: Also it sounds like you make be making player a bunch of times and not realizing you have copies on screen

Comment: Thanks, i will see if "unowned" works